# How to scale width of the carousel across the entire page

Tags: carousel

[image]

```
<div>
        <carousel>
          <slide>
            <img src="ny.jpg" alt="First slide">
            <div class="caption">
              <h4>Launch of Mount Eliza </h4>
            </div>
          </slide>
          <slide>
            <img src="chicago.jpg" alt="Second slide">
            <div class="caption">
              <h4>Launch of Mount Eliza </h4>
            </div>
          </slide>
          <slide>
            <img src="mex.jpg" alt="Third slide">
            <div class="caption">
              <h4>Launch of Mount Eliza </h4>
            </div>
          </slide>
        </carousel>
      </div>
```

I tried many solutions to adjust the width of the carousel. But its happening. I want to make the carousel to stretch across the entire width of the page. I also want to get rid of the white space in between nav bar and carousel. How to achieve this? 
Note : I have a nav bar header above this carousel and I am making carousel as a separate component. So i think setting html body to 100% wont work . Because I have few more sections below the carousel. I cant set the width manually to some % because i want it to be responsive.I tried the below code and it didnt work.

```
.carousel
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;

.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the image width all same size. I would try a width of 1903px. Make sure that the carousel is not in a container.

White space will either be padding or margin. Only with a link to the site can someone see what it is.

Keith

Comment: Image width is of same size. Increasing the image wont work because i need to increase the carousel width.

Comment: Where is the code for the above link ? specifically the css classes .. Its the same design i am looking .. A nav bar with a carousel close to the nav bar without any spaces.Also a width of 1903 px will not support responsive design ..

Comment: Open page in Chrome. Right click > view page source. You can then see html and css used. Note extra css file carousel.css.

That example keeps a static height on the carousel. There are various threads on here with suggestions on how to make it fully responsive.